# How do I select 'flag' options for magit through helm?

Tags: spacemacs, magit, helm

I'm using spacemacs with helm and magit. There are some options, for example, the ability to sort log entries in reverse order, that have a flag by them.

[image: options for commit ordering in helm interface]

I don't know how to select any of these options. If I type in '-r', the flag gets selected but nothing happens. If I press `enter` or `tab`, I get an error that the key is unbound. I've looked through magit's and spacemacs' documentation, but couldn't find anything about how to actually execute these options. What is the key combination I'm supposed to press to actually use the option?

Comment: You probably want to look at the [manual for transient](https://magit.vc/manual/transient/Introduction.html) (that's the library magit uses to make those popup window things, helm is not relevant, I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my screenshot of the magit `log` popup.

[image]

There are a series of switches and options. As you said, you can press, e.g. `-r` to toggle the "Show in reverse order switch". Pressing that should toggle the option, causing it to show up in a bold red color. In my screenshot, the `--graph` and `--decorate` options are selected. When you select an option, the only thing that changes is flagging the options for later.

To make the option take effect, we need to perform an action. At the bottom, the actions are listed. You can think of them as being final; they tell Magit to do the action, as modified by the options you previously chose. So by pressing (from my screenshot) `h`, magit displays the log at HEAD, with the `--graph` and `--decorate` options selected.

At the bottom of your screen, you should have something similar.